# how to set the min and max protocol versions in openssl library

Tags: c, struct, openssl

I could not find out how to set the min and max protocol version in [this](https://github.com/openssl/openssl) library:

There is a function:
`static int test_func(void)` in a test file

```
sysdefaulttest.c
```

That uses the min and max protocol version:

```
static int test_func(void) {
if (!TEST_int_eq(SSL_CTX_get_min_proto_version(ctx), TLS1_2_VERSION)
    && !TEST_int_eq(SSL_CTX_get_max_proto_version(ctx), TLS1_2_VERSION)) {
    TEST_info("min/max version setting incorrect");
    return 0;
}
return 1;}
```

This test fails in my case. The 'ctx' context struct has these 2 values as zero in my case. It looks like these have to be set somewhere in the library.

```
ctx.min_proto_ver, ctx.max_proto_ver
```

Both of the above are showing Zero value in my case.

```
SSL_CTX_get_min_proto_version(ctx);
SSL_CTX_get_max_proto_version(ctx);
```

Where can I set these version values in the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably with

- `SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version` and
- `SSL_CTX_set_max_proto_version`

functions (https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/include/openssl/ssl.h.in#L1451).

From [docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_set_min_proto_version.html):

> The setter functions were added in OpenSSL 1.1.0. The getter functions were added in OpenSSL 1.1.1.

---

EDIT
In the test, however, you should not have to do anything. After building the library you would run the test like this:

```
]$ make TESTS="test_sysdefault" test
...
90-test_sysdefault.t .. ok
All tests successful.
Files=1, Tests=1,  0 wallclock secs ( 0.00 usr  0.00 sys +  0.11 cusr  0.01 csys =  0.12 CPU)
Result: PASS
```

This executes test recipe from `test/recipes/90-test_sysdefault.t`, which sets `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable to `test/sysdefault.cnf`. This configuration file sets protocol version to 1.2:

```
]$ cat ./test/sysdefault.cnf
# Configuration file to test system default SSL configuration
...
[ssl_default_sect]
MaxProtocol = TLSv1.2
MinProtocol = TLSv1.2
```

and the test should load this file:

```c
int global_init(void)
{
    if (!OPENSSL_init_ssl(OPENSSL_INIT_ENGINE_ALL_BUILTIN
                          | OPENSSL_INIT_LOAD_CONFIG, NULL))
```

Knowing that, the test can be executed directly doing the same:

```
]$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. OPENSSL_CONF=test/sysdefault.cnf ./test/sysdefaulttest
1..1
ok 1 - test_func
```

(here I had to additionally use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` because I've only built the library and I haven't installed it)

If we want to verify that `sysdefault.cnf` is really opened, we can use `strace`:

```
]$ LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. OPENSSL_CONF=test/sysdefault.cnf strace -f -e trace=/open ./test/sysdefaulttest
openat(AT_FDCWD, "./tls/haswell/x86_64/libssl.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
...
openat(AT_FDCWD, "test/sysdefault.cnf", O_RDONLY) = 3
1..1
ok 1 - test_func
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Comment: should I use these macros inside the sysdefaulttest.c file or should I do it somewhere else?

Comment: I think that usually you would run this test using `make TESTS="test_sysdefault" test` and in that case you should not have to do anything, because this will run a `90-test_sysdefault.t` recipe, which sets `OPENSSL_CONF` environment variable to `sysdefault.cnf` and this configuration file sets min and max to 1.2.

Comment: If you run the test directly, you can do the same: `OPENSSL_CONF=sysdefault.cnf ./sysdefaulttest`.

Comment: Can you tell me where can I learn in more detail about the process that you have mentioned in your above two comments? I am not able to run these successfully.. must be missing some details in here..

Comment: Sorry, don't know. It was mostly looking for files that contain "sysdefault" in their name or in their content, maybe a bit of googling. I've updated the answer to include the info from the comment. I also added the bit about "strace", which can be used to confirm if the expected configuration file was opened.